# Link Django-cookie sessionId to Channels 2.02 connection?

Tags: django, session, websocket, django-channels, anonymous-users

Thank you all for reading my first post. Using Django 2.02, Django-channels 2.02.

I wish to store informations that get send from the frontend to the backend into Django session store. My problem is that the Django-channels session scope only seems to store information as long as the WebSocket is open, but I need it store it like a Django http-session.

First javascript from frontend index.html.

```
<script>
const conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/');

var msg = {
    type: "message",
    message: "Trying to find a solution",
    date: Date.now(),
};

msg = JSON.stringify(msg);
conn.onopen = () => conn.send(msg);
</script>
```

Consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import JsonWebsocketConsumer
from importlib import import_module
from django.conf import settings
SessionStore = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE).SessionStore
#Have tried SessionStore to store but will also not work

class ConnectConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text_data=None):
        text = self.decode_json(text_data) #decode incoming JSON
        text_message = text.get('message') 

        print(self.scope["session"]["message"]) #prints "None"
        self.scope["session"]["message"] = text_message
        self.scope['session'].save()
        print(self.scope["session"]["message"]) #prints "Trying to find a solution"

    def disconnect(self, message):
        pass
```

Routing.py

```
from django.urls import path
from channels.http import AsgiHandler
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from consumers import ConnectConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            path("/", ConnectConsumer),
        ]),
    )
})
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    print(request.session.keys()) #returns Empty dict([])
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
    )
```

Please tell me if this question is to broad or I am missing relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `views.py` code to

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    if not 'message' in request.session.keys():
        request.session['message'] = ''
        print("'message' key created in HTTP session")    
    print(request.session['message']) # it should print "" on the first run
                                      # and "Trying to find a solution" after that
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
    )
```

I'm not quite sure about what causes this issue, but I guess that it is related with the way that the `SessionMiddleware` works. It seems that the `SessionStore.save()` method does not save new session keys when called inside the `consumers.py`. That's why I preallocate the 'message' key in the `views.py`.

---

Edit 1 - my `consumers.py`

```
from channels.generic.websocket import JsonWebsocketConsumer
#from importlib import import_module
from django.conf import settings
#SessionStore = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE).SessionStore
#Have tried SessionStore to store but will also not work

class ConnectConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text_data=None):
        text = self.decode_json(text_data) #decode incoming JSON
        text_message = text.get('message') 

        print(self.scope["session"]["message"]) 
        self.scope["session"]["message"] = text_message
        self.scope['session'].save()
        print(self.scope["session"]["message"]) #prints "Trying to find a solution"

    def disconnect(self, message):
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you for answer bjbschmitt. I tried this but views.py and consumers.py(SessionStore) store information in different session_keys. Can you please post an example of how your consumers.py looks?

Comment: I have used the same `consumers.py` as you. But I'll add it to my answer anyway. Btw, could you please show me your `settings.py` file? Maybe it is something related with your sessions settings.

Comment: It now works PERFECTLY! I am sorry, it was my mistake. I tried different solutions, so when I was trying this one, I mixed it up with another solution. I am greatfull.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a little bit old, but I lost a total day of figuring out why cookies are not being send over the websocket connection and therefore I could not access the correct session in the consumer.
Turns out I just had to replace

```
new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/');
```

with

```
new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

Other than that, it really is important to save the session or the new session key first outside of the consumer (e.g. in a View) like shown in @bjbschmitt answer.

I hope this will save someone a lot of time.