# Need help accessing session variables in Django Channels consumers.py

Tags: python, django, django-channels, django-sessions

I am generating a random userid and storing it as a session variable in my view. I am trying to access that session variable in consumers.py to identify the user (not authenticated ) and update the user about the changes in the database.

view.py :

```
def index(request):
        request.session['uniqueid'] = 'random_number'
        print(request.session['uniqueid']) # this is working 
    return render(
        request,
        'home.html',
    )
```

consumers.py:

```
class WSConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        U = self.scope['session']["uniqueid"]
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: connect) 'uniqueid'
```

I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 ('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/socket/') as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67242832, but receive the same error.

I am unable to pin down the error, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: put `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` then when it pauses there take a look at self.scope and poke around some more :) sorry thats all ive got for you at the moment

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: no I was not able to solve the problem. I tried to debug and look at self.scope but I do not see any session variables coming through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mark the session as **"modified"** to make sure it gets saved.

Indeed **SessionMiddleware** check if `request.session` was modified, or if the configuration is to save the
session every time, save the changes and set a session cookie or delete
the session cookie if the session has been emptied.

```
def index(request):
        session = request.session 
        session['uniqueid'] = 'random_number'
        session.modified = True  
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Also `print` in your view function return **cached value** nor pesistent value.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I think you are right the session was not being saved.